# Laravel Redirect Returns Nothing

Tags: php, redirect, laravel

I'm just starting out in Laravel. I am trying a simple redirect, however, I get an empty page as a response, and the Browser is not redirected.

```
Route::get('last', [
    'as' => 'theLast',
    function(){
        Redirect::route('theFirst');
    }
]);

Route::get('first', [
    'as' => 'theFirst',
    function(){
        return 'First';
}
```

When I hit /first, I receive 'First' in response, as expected.
However, when I hit /last, I would expect to be redirected to /first, but I am not redirected, and I hit /last, with no error, but an empty page.
In case it matters, I am running php5.5.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return the response;

```
return Redirect::route('theFirst');
```

Comment: Ok, I see. I figured that I am redirecting to another route, and that route is what is doing the actual returning.

Comment: @Ben No it is not, Laravel's Response class returns a header('Location'), all that the ::route() does it look up the path to redirect to.